# How to store the results of this function in an individual array for every input entered in the form?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arraylist

```js
function post(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = document.getElementById("data");
  var nameValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
  const pname = document.getElementById("pname").value;
  const ptype = document.getElementById("ptype").value;

  const name = document.createElement("p");
  name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameValue));
  name.setAttribute("class", "perName");
  
  data.appendChild(name);

  const product_type = document.createElement("p");
  product_type.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ptype));
  product_type.setAttribute("class", "prodType");
  
  data.appendChild(product_type);

  const product_name = document.createElement("p");
  product_name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pname));
  product_name.setAttribute("class", "prodName");
  
  data.appendChild(product_name);

  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

```css
*,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#myForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

label {
  padding-top: 7px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.datas {
  background-color: teal;
  padding: 5px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 2%;
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Share and care</title>
  </head>

  <body>


    <!-- body -->

    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="return post(event);">
      <label for="">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="personName" id="name" />

      <label for="">Your product</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="ptype" />

      <label for="">Product Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="pname" />

      <button type="submit">Post</button>

    </form>
    
      <!-- inputdisplay -->
      
    <div class="datas">
      <div id="data"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="result"></div>
    
    <footer></footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hello devs! I am a newbie webdev. Pls help me solve this basic problem.

Here I have three text fields. So every time the submit button is clicked the input values are stored and  a new `<p>` is created for every input and there are displayed below. Now i need to get the values from that function and store in array. So everytime  a submit is clicked the new object is to be pushed inside the array for individual persons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating an empty array (outside of the submit handler function)

```
const arr = [];
```

To push the data to the array, on every submit, do:

```
arr.push({ name: nameValue, productType: ptype, productName: pname });
```